# Cairngorm quickstart

Tags: apache-flex, frameworks, cairngorm

Searching the site didn't help, so if anybody has good tips for getting up to speed with Cairngorm?!
I have to make an ultra quickstart on this framework, since I have to dive into an existing project ASAP.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guys created a Flex application to help explain the work flow:
http://robsondesign.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/18/cairngorm-diagram-explorer-update/

Comment: Thanks for the response, indeed very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I found this 5 part tutorial at [www.davidtucker.net](http://www.davidtucker.net/category/cairngorm/) to be very practical and hands on. David moves fast but also gives solid descriptions for almost everything he does. The tutorial includes both blog posts and video code-alongs. I recommend doing both. The download files get a little messed up (renaming, Adobe AIR, Flex Web app), so I had to follow the code-alongs and use the downloaded source only for reference (I opened in a separate editor and copy and pasted as needed).

Answer (score 1):

you don't mention which version of Cairngorm, but this is a good place to start if you are using version 2.1 or earlier.

[cairngorm docs](http://www.cairngormdocs.org/)

The beta for Cairngorm 3 is out and you can find whatever info there currently is at

[cairngorm 3](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm+3)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a simple animated short about Cairngorm](http://www.alamgirdesigns.com/2009/01/flex-animated-cairngorm-tutorial/)

Then you need to understand the [MVC architectural pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)

[Why to use design patterns (inspiration/motivation)](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/gammadp.html)

Then go ahead to these Cairngorm related links/videos:

[Getting started links](http://bie.no/blog/computers/software-engineering/actionscript/2007/01/getting-started-with-cairngorm/)

[Video tutorials](http://www.davidtucker.net/category/cairngorm/)

Then start coding:

[A real case to work with](http://www.digimmersion.com/support/Flex%20UI%20Design%20For%20Cairngorm.pdf)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply.
Have got a good insight meanwhile, nonetheless your links were very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a book from Wrox on Amazon that really helped me [Professional Cairngorm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470497262)